# Eclipse program g++ not found in path Linux Mint 15

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, g++, linux-mint

ok I have a new clean Linux Mint 15. I have download/installed the GCC tool chain, Eclipse. Then I migrated my code that is on my windows box to my new installation and removed all the little files eclipse loves insert. 
Then I created a new C/C++ project (NAV_IOP), and my workspace is in the tree itself ie:
/nexgen/CodeBase/NAV/NAV_IOP. My code is in two directories below NAV_IOP {CDU-host and CDU-Includes}.

My Code has no errors as I can compile it in a terminal with no errors (gcc )
My Eclipse says "program g++ not found in path" duh, I dont want to use g++, I just want to use gcc.

under Window > Preferences > Build > Settings: 
Discovery: ALL are CDT GCC

under Project > Properties > Builder:
empty

what is missing please help....
Thanks
Cris

Comment: Just install g++. the CDT expects it to be present, regardless of whether you're going to use it for your project or not. If g++ is available from the terminal, then there are several other answers on the stack exchange network which would help you with this

Comment: Ok so I just installed g++ and reloaded Eclipse.. now no errors... but still no love.. press the hammer and nothing happens.. when I press the debug button it says no recent launch....